# Using asp.net core Kestrel for serving static file from a local folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to create a Kestrel web server which will serve static file from a local folder path ( eg: C:\Website). But my web server is not getting started or its not able to find  the file. Giving below my code

**Working Code**

```
     var host = new WebHostBuilder()
             .UseKestrel()
             .UseContentRoot(@"C:\Website")        
             .UseStartup<Startup>()
             .Build();

   Task.Run(()=> host.RunAsync())
```

below is my Configure method

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
        {
            FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
        @"C:\Website"),
            RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
        });

    }
```

but when i am trying to access my index.html file inside the folder with the url http://localhost:5000/StaticFiles/index.html it is not working . I am getting the error **localhost didn’t send any data.ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE** . Is there any thing i am missing . When i run the application in debug mode i can see the below log in visual studio output window

**Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Website
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Now listening on: https://localhost:5001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.**

Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Sure you aren't missing `Run`?

Comment: I have run just below the hosting @patrick

Comment: What do the logs say when you actually try to access the path in the browser?

Comment: In browser i am not seeing any log.  but if i  keep fiddler open i am getting [Fiddler] ReadResponse() failed: The server did not return a complete response for this request. Server returned 0 bytes.

Comment: You should probably add logging to your web host builder, so that you get some feedback from it. `.ConfigureLogging(l => l.AddConsole())` should do the trick.

Comment: Finally got it working. actual issue was I was starting the server from a wpf viewmodel. so i have to call the run method  asynchronously. also instead of host.run i need to use host.runaync(). Also after some more changes to the threading related part, I was able to get it working .

Comment: I still can't get it to run.... any answers to this?? What did you do??